# Maven dependencies source code

Tags: java, maven

I am building an automated tool that at some time should download, for some packages, the source code. To do that, for each package I use the command:

mvn dependency:get artifact:group id:artifact id:version:jar:sources

now for most of dependencies it works fine. It is downloaded the jar sources file, the jar binary file and the pom.xml.
The problem is that there are very few packages I am not able to find on maven central repository (the official one).

For example, in my last test 48 packages out of 490 were not found. here the list:

```
ant.ant-1.6.2
antlr.antlr-2.7.7
asm.asm-3.3.1
asm.asm-tree-3.3.1
asm.asm-util-3.3.1
avalon-framework.avalon-framework-4.1.3
avalon-framework.avalon-framework-4.1.5
bouncycastle.bcmail-jdk14-138
bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk14-138
com.caucho.hessian-4.0.7
com.google.code.findbugs.jsr305-1.3.9
com.google.inject.guice-2.0
com.infradna.tool.bridge-method-annotation-1.13
commons-beanutils.commons-beanutils-core-1.7.0
commons-codec.commons-codec-1.2
commons-logging.commons-logging-1.0.2
commons-logging.commons-logging-1.0.3
commons-logging.commons-logging-api-1.1
eclipse.jdtcore-3.1.0
jakarta-regexp.jakarta-regexp-1.4
jfree.jcommon-1.0.15
jfree.jfreechart-1.0.12
ldapsdk.ldapsdk-4.1
net.java.dev.jna.jna-platform
net.sourceforge.findbugs.annotations-1.3.2
org.apache.derby.derby-10.12.1.1
org.apache.derby.derbyclient-10.12.1.1
org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.0
org.apache.poi.poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13
org.apache.velocity.velocity-1.6.2
org.apache.velocity.velocity-tools-2.0
org.apache.xmlbeans.xmlbeans-2.6.0
org.beanshell.bsh-2.0b4
org.beanshell.bsh-core-2.0b4
org.eclipse.persistence.javax.persistence-2.0.0
org.flywaydb.flyway-core-3.2.1
org.webjars.npm.validate.js-0.8.0
stax.stax-api-1.0.1
velocity-tools.velocity-tools-view-1.4
velocity.velocity-1.5
xalan.serializer-2.7.1
xerces.xercesImpl-2.6.0
xerces.xercesImpl-2.9.0
xerces.xercesImpl-2.9.1
xerces.xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2
xml-apis.xml-apis-1.3.03
xml-apis.xml-apis-ext-1.3.04
```

Is there a way to download the source code for this (in a way that can be invoked in a script)? Is there any maven repository I can add to the list of my repository that contains these packages?
Thanks

Comment: Just accept the fact that for certain dependencies (or dependency versions) there are no sources in a maven repository

Comment: Is it possible add an alternative repository? If no, is there a way to know the main website download location? For example, if there is a way to download them from other sources (i.e github).

Comment: May I ask: Why do you need all this source code?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html

Comment: Yes. I have to build an automation tool for my company that analyze a project built by 3rdparty in order to discover all the 3rd party open source dependencies, I am able to retrieve the list of dependency and for each of them I want download the source code and execute another tool against it to generate a report. The only problem I have so far is that I am not able to download for 48 packages out of 490 the source code, so for them I have to execute the process manually and this is unacceptable for me.

Comment: I read the documentation about maven dependency plugin

Comment: There is certainly a way to find the sources (provided those dependencies are licensed open source which most of them appear to be).  However, it is not going to be standardized or consistent.  For example, to get the ant source you can go to http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/source/